# Broken faded border effect in CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to achieve the teal colored border as shown

[image]

As, you can see, the border here does not have a consistent pattern, It is broken/faded at random positions. If not the exact, i would like to have the closest looking.

Is this possible with CSS. If not, any alternate to achieve that.

There is an border-image property but for that, I would need such image. 
I have no idea of photoshop. So, the only options are CSS or using an image. 
I would also appreciate suggestions where I can find such border images.

https://jsfiddle.net/2oeb569z/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #131313;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 330px;
  height: 230px;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.content {  
  height: 90%;
  border: 0px solid teal;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(teal), to(transparent));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(teal, transparent);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(teal, transparent), -moz-linear-gradient(teal, transparent);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(teal, transparent), -o-linear-gradient(teal, transparent);
  background-image: linear-gradient(teal, transparent), linear-gradient(teal, transparent);
  -moz-background-size: 7px 100%;
  background-size: 7px 100%;
  background-position: 0% 0, 100% 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "teal" border? You can use images as borders. It means that you can achieve any effect you want.

Comment: I meant the color. Unlike other border images, this is not symmetric. It is randomly faded. Any idea where I can find such borders. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an image with some pattern of randomly faded borders. You can make it big enough that it fits any object that you want to have a border. When you create a border you crop the image. You can also have separate images for the top and left border.

Answer (score 0):

I have found some border frames [here](http://www.freepik.com/free-photos-vectors/border), mostly are in psd.

You will have to use photoshop to edit, or the best way will be making your own using photoshop. It will be easy to achieve this by using border images.

Comment: I have provided the link because you asked for, why downvotes? You have to use border images.

Comment: Thats the funny thing here. Nobody knows who downvoted and why. Happened to this question too. :) But thanks for the link. Im still searching for the closest border. Two questions. Can I use these images with border-image prop. & can those border colors be changes? i dont think so.

Answer (score -1):

I created One effect using gradient try this,You can use image that is better

```css
  #grad1 {
 

height: 200px;
width:300px;
background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,#eaeaea,#fbfbfb 7%,#e6e6e6 10%); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,#eaeaea,#fbfbfb 7%,#e6e6e6 10%);/* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,#eaeaea,#fbfbfb 7%,#e6e6e6 10%); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


</head>
<body>


<div id="grad1"></div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Im sorry rinto, but i do not know how this answer is going to help me. Im looking for a rectangular border. Could you plz show what you wanted to in the rectangle way. I hope my original post was clear to you about what was needed.

Comment: Here i am using gradient-linear_repeating. If you want more details about  this method visit this link http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_gradient-linear_repeating

Comment: You are trying to achieve the background in the image  I have shared. right?

Comment: No, its just a demo for your question

Answer (score -2):

perhaps this would work?

```
border: 2px solid rgba(79, 211, 255, 0.2);
```

the `rgba(red, green, blue, hardness)` allows you both to specify a color and give it some opacity level, hence you can create some fading affect

Comment: Oh that was not the effect I wanted. It's not opacity. If you see, the border is broken/faded at random places.